# Do I have to remove VS 2010 beta1 in order to get a web app to work on asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2010

I think the title is enough :). I have VS 2010 beta1 installed, and I wish to run an asp.net mvc application on my local IIS. The problem is, the asp.net 4.0 runtime is selected by default for all the web sites, when I try to change it to asp.net 2.0, I get the following error message: 
[alt text http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/7946/iiserror.jpg](http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/7946/iiserror.jpg)

I click yes, then ok, and when I get back to the ASP.NET tab of my site's properties, I see the 4.0 version is selected back again! Do I have to remove VS 2010 in order to get this to work? (hopefully not)

Ps: I'm using windows XP and IIS 5.1

Comment: Of course, you should probably try to run your site under .NET 4.0, so you can report any problems to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the **Default** for your IIS it does not mean that it will change the value on all the sites. You will need to go change them individually back to 2.0